# Linq Retorno todos os registros quando ID for NULL

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda, linq-to-entities

## Consulta:

```
retorno = tarefaRep.GetAll(c => c.status == 0
                                  && c.id_empresa == idEmpresa
                                  && c.id_cliente.ToString().Equals(idCliente)
                                  && c.id_colaborador.ToString().Equals(idColaborador),
                                 limit, ctx);
```

`idCliente` e `idColaborador` podem ser nulos, neste caso eu gostaria de retornar todos os registros, o que devo ajustar?

Comment: alessandre fiz uma modificação que creio melhorar o entendimento da sua pergunta. caso não esteja de acordo me avisa que retorno como era :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

veja se lhe atende:

```
retorno = tarefaRep.GetAll(c => c.status == 0
                              && c.id_empresa == idEmpresa
                              && (idCliente == null ? true : c.id_cliente.ToString().Contains(idCliente))
                              && (idColaborador == null ? true : c.id_colaborador.ToString().Contains(idColaborador)),
                             limit, ctx);
```